# What's the point of the disarm action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, disarming

The Disarm action is designed to knock an object out of the holder's hand and presumably into the holder's space. Because enemies aren't allowed to enter that space, nobody will be able to pick up the weapon in that time, especially in a duel. But picking the item back up is a free object interaction on the holder's next turn.

This means that, except for in corner cases, disarming an enemy doesn't cost them anything.

So what's it for?

Edit: This question has not already been answered, since the top answer of the linked question interprets the rules for Disarming very differently, which conflicts with my question.

Comment: This question has not already been answered, since the top answer of the linked question interprets the rules for Disarming very differently, which conflicts with my question.

Comment: Just because you don't like the answer doesn't change the fact that the question is the same.

Comment: It's the *answer* — the one with 24 votes — that makes the assertion, not the question. I suppose you could technically revise this question to say "assuming the reading given here is wrong, and Disarm actually does" … whatever it is you think it does differently (I actually can't tell). Be prepared for an answer that says "Well, that assumption is not valid, because ABC", however.

Comment: I added another answer to the linked question, which I think *is* a perfectly appropriate answer to your question as well. If it isn't, please edit your question to clarify the conflict you're referring to.

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you asking about the Disarm action option in the DMG, the Battle Master fighter's Disarming Attack maneuver, or something else? (That said, the linked question seems to basically cover all such forms of disarming that cause the target to drop the item in/near their space.)

Answer (score 2):

- If you're disarmed, you remain so for a *reaction*.
- If you're disarmed, you may be unable to *parry* on someone else's turn.
- You can disarm an opponent to force it to drop its shield, and get an easier follow-up attack.
- You can disarm an opponent to force it to drop some other item for whatever purpose.
- If you disarm an opponent and follow-up with a shove, the item is no longer at its feet.

Comment: How do you disarm and shove in the same turn?

Comment: There are a number of ways. Shove replaces only a single attack (if you have multiple). L2 Fighter can use an _action surge_. And if push comes to shove (pun intended) using team-work, an ally can do the shoving.

Comment: Note that whether disarm can be used against a shield is the subject of another question; when I'm not on mobile I could find you a link.